# Should I tell my project manager that I am not capable to do a task that even a senior can't do?

Tags: software-industry, software-development

I am on my way to the final month of the probation period which is the third month before knowing that I should look for a new job. I start as a junior developer and work with a framework that I never touched before. (It is too futuristic for me.)

The only senior that we have are work in a different department said he cannot do it.

The first month everything went good. I thought it was going to be fine.
Then the second month came. Everything is rolling from the top of the hill.

I stuck at one task for 3 weeks. I feel dumbfound. I told my project manager, I will take a long time to finish this nearly impossible task. Because in the document it's said that the framework currently does not support this yet.
Many forums also confirm my theory that it cannot be done yet. The device is not that good; the framework is not stable yet.

I am stressful every day. I had a migraine every day. 
I don't love to go to work anymore.
I explain (not directly) to them it is impossible to do; they still want me to do it anyway.
I cannot do that. I can do anything else but this. It is not possible ...at the moment!
When I was an intern I create an app that was more complex than this, because it was possible to do so.

This task is not possible in the present time. I told them maybe because I cannot say I can't do it loudly. I want to tell them that, but I don't want it to cost my first job. (I'm still looking for a new job anyway.)

Comment: Yes, you should tell him. Otherwise, you're wasting the company's time. So maybe the question you should ask is *how* to do so, considering you're still on probabation. Also, could you add a culture/location tag?

Comment: Also check out this question: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/137832/started-new-job-given-difficult-impossible-project-what-to-do/137855#137855

Comment: You've written a very rambling post which does not manage to make it clear if you have **a)** not figured out how to approach the problem **b)** conclusively demonstrated that the framework lacks support and feel you are unable to figure out how to add it or **c)** determined that some aspect of the framework actually makes it *impossible* for support to be added by anyone, and that the framework itself cannot be altered.  You need to clearly identify what the situation is, and then work on clearly expressing that if you want to remain in this role.  Otherwise, work on finding your next.

Comment: (An example of (c) where something is actually *impossible* is that on iOS there are things you are simply not allowed to do - it doesn't matter how important the business requirement is, Apple just will not let you or anyone else do that with their device, and a different idea must be pursued)

Comment: they gave me many theories about how it should be (it should work now they said). I work as they instruct every line. result still no change at all. even now they have no idea how to proceed and why it is not working as they thought it would be.

Comment: Please re-read your question. There is some sentences that grammatically just don't make sense and it makes it hard to figure out what exactly your question is about.
Two examples: 
I.) "because in the document say so that framework that currently something to do 'something they want me to do' yet"
II.) "the device that that good. the framework that yet stable."  

I think it is also important to clarify whether the task is objectively impossible, really hard to achieve, or you dpn't know how to do it yet..

Comment: When the senior developer says he cannot do it, is he sayings its impossible for him to do it? or because he can't be bothered to do it? A lot of the time, Senior Developers have focused on their own projects and do not have the time to help support another team

Comment: oh, I am really 'sorry' i am not from a country that uses English as the 1st language. it is the third one. if you bother a lot it is easier to ignore.

Comment: @Shadowzee He shows me how and teach me. He expected a different result. but no it is not we tried together many times for 3 weeks. He used to work with this framework before. but now he works with IoT, not this one that I work on.

Comment: today they finally accept it that it is not possible for now. phew we moved on next project now. Thank you for every advice. i will work better next project

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should put your analysis of the problem in writing and give it to the project manager. Explain what would be needed to make it feasible, and exactly why it is not feasible as currently proposed. Make your analysis very clear and direct. If you can see alternatives that would help with the business objective and that are feasible, describe them.

Ask for guidance on how to proceed. There is a possibility that you have misunderstood something about the requirements or proposed implementation, but documenting your current thinking will help resolve that.

Comment: I asked for help. they gave me many theories about how it should be (it should work now they said). I work as they want. result still no change at all.
even now they have no idea how to proceed and why it is not working as they thought it would be. but they want me to do it anyway. they expected too much from junior like me.

Answer (score 3):

As Project Manager I would like to receive your feedback. But be clear in your message and give some fundamentals to it. Stand in your point of view but be open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, getting asked to do the 'impossible' is part of the job.

the only thing I can advise you to do is to talk to your manager, say you've been trying to get it to work but it really isn't possible. Not "nearly impossible", not "it will take a long time", but "The framework doesn't support it".
Add in that you checked with your colleague. It adds validity to your statement.

The next thing to do is ensure that this won't happen again.

I would advise you to start new projects with going through the assignment and looking for pitfalls or difficult to impossible tasks. Check for solutions and how long they would take.(this would take about 5%-10% of the time you get for the project. some companies )
Then, go to your manager

For the future tough. Try to make sure you take a bit of time at the start of a project.
Look for pitfalls and things that could be difficult or impossible. and if you see them. Notify your manager immediately, preferably with the time it would take to fix said issues, or an alternative solution

Comment: yea will do. I already told them at the begining. still not sure why they thought i can do it. my co worker (that join company same time as me) got easy job (even i dont know about #C  I can do it). i only one that get big one. why why???? .

Answer (score -1):

This happens a lot. If I were you, I wouldn't fight it. Document the problems I am facing everyday. I might succeed or you might fail.

If I fail I have my reasons to show(if I cannot find a job before that).

In parallel I will look for a new job. The pain is not going to end with this task.
When we work with people we have to interpret and work with subconscious biases. As you might have seen in this forum itself negative question and answers would put people in bad light.Same at workplace.
If any of my team members raise an alarm about an issue the seriousness depends on how seriously I take them. They are not taking you or your issue seriously.

Don't let negatively slip from your side to your bosses. People are super judgemental about this.
Instead of siding and supporting you they will call you with names like "attitude problem", "incompetent", "slow learner" etc..
In the meantime some incompetent guy will come, may you work on it and steals credit.

Comment: this is pretty negative thinking for me.  they are nice to me. but they only give hard task to me.